# Capturing concurrent connection data

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tcp

I have a server with multiple incoming tcp long lived connections to the same port. I would like to capture each connection's incoming data to a separate file. The incoming data is a continuous stream of data, i.e. the sender just sends data continuously. I have tried using

```
ncat -l -k -m 10 -o <file>
```

but the -o option sends the data from all connections to the same file and I want to keep each connection's data in a separate file so that incoming data does not overlap. I can write a program to do this but would be good if there is anything out of the box since it seems like a common use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create **command.sh** script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > /tmp/output-$NCAT_REMOTE_ADDR-$NCAT_REMOTE_PORT-$NCAT_LOCAL_ADDR-$NCAT_LOCAL_PORT.txt
```

And then run ncat like following:

```
 ncat -l -k -m 10 -p 9020 -c "./command.sh"
```

This will create separate output file for each connection. And file name will be like this:

```
output-127.0.0.1-45329-127.0.0.1-9020.txt
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks for that